# Finding number of pairs of integers in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Recently bumped into a hackerrank challenge, got to find pair of int in a given array. 
Using ArrayList as an approach.
Can anyone rectify the errors in this code.

Error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 9

at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)

at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)

at Solution.main(Solution.java:32)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int c[] = new int[n];
        for(int c_i=0; c_i < n; c_i++){
            c[c_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int count=0;

        Arrays.sort(c);

        ArrayList<Integer> ch = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int c_i=0; c_i < n; c_i++){
           ch.add(c[c_i]);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<ch.size();i++){
            int a = ch.get(i);
            int b=ch.indexOf(a);
            if(b<0)
                continue;
            else{ 
                ch.remove(a);
                ch.remove(b);
                count++;
                for (int j=0;j<ch.size()-2;j++){
                    ch.add(j,ch.get(j+2));

                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
```

Edited the above approach and while finding that `b` will give the index of `a` removing only one element always, so now tried the approach that the first element is removed no matter what and then searching for the matching pair element until the arrayList is empty.

```
while(ch.size()!=0){
        int a = ch.get(0);
        ch.remove(0);
        int b = ch.indexOf(a);
        if(b<0){

            for (int j=0;j<ch.size()-1;j++)
                ch.add(j,ch.get(j+1));
            continue; 
            }
        else{ 

            ch.remove(b);
            count++;
            for (int j=0;j<ch.size()-2;j++)
                ch.add(j,ch.get(j+2));
            }
     }



Error: Terminated due to timeout
```

Comment: If `a = ch.get(i)`, what stops `b` being equal to `i`?

Comment: The error is going to occur at this line `ch.remove(a);` as in your program `a` can be a number that is greater than the size of `Arraylist`.

Comment: Any other alternatives removing the elements from the array so they dont hamper with the search. Also I'm removing the elements, so they dont come in the way of another recursive pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = ch.get(i);
```

This will retrieve the value at location i

```
ch.remove(a);
```

This will remove the value stored at index `a`. The value `a` could be possibly greater than the ArrayList size.

This is where you are going wrong. Try commenting that out, maybe it will work

Comment: I'm using the approach that if we have a pair of elements, we remove the pair to start the process again of finding and removing. In this way, the possibility of finding recursive pairs is eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if some one needs a different approach to find total number of pairs in a arraylist.    
int pair=0;
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();//your input



    Set<Integer> uniqueSet = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
        for (Integer temp : uniqueSet) {
            System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));



            if(Collections.frequency(list, temp)==2|| Collections.frequency(list, temp)>2)
            {
     int t=Collections.frequency(list, temp)/2;
     pair=pair+t;
            }


        }
        return pair;
```